# apps on SD card when switching phones

Tags: lumia, 8.1

Start off my old and new phone is a Nokia Lumia 1520.
I also have Windows Phone 8.1 installed on both phones.

I got a new phone because my last one was damaged.  I have good amount of games on my SD card from my old phone.  When I take my SD cardout of the old phone and put it in the new phone, I see the amount of space used on the SD card is correct but there is nothing under "apps+games".   It appears all my apps is stored under "other" on the SD card and other states

"These are file types we don't recognize that didn't fit in with the rest. You can try connecting your phone to your computer and managing them there."

Is there a way I can make those apps usable on my new phone?

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/692/106

Comment: I'm not asking how to get a app I paid for.  I already know how to download the app again.  I just don't want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, it's not possible to use any games or apps installed on an SD card from a different phone.**

[Apps and games are stored in an encrypted form on the SD card](https://expertcentre.nokia.com/en/articles/news/Pages/Enhanced-security-in-Nokia-Lumia-with-Windows-Phone-8-1.aspx), and the encryption keys (ie. the access to that data) are kept by the phone that installed them.

Comment: Is there any way to remove these application files from the other phone?

Comment: @NK no - for security reasons.

Comment: I really don't see the need for this security.   Whenever you have a purchased item installed it checks to make sure you've bought it.   Also because of this security I lost the free 9 Gameloft Games I got back in April.  Apparently you can't download them again?  At least I haven't figured out how.

Comment: @Michael One security scenario: If the apps *weren't* encrypted/tied to a specific device, the SD card could be removed, have malware inserted into the app, and replace into the phone (or many other phones). Perhaps it would in retrospect encrypt with a key tied to the user account, but that was a design decision Microsoft took. Additionally, there is no guarantee that the same files would work for a different device, as developers *can* deploy different versions, for different screen resolutions. In both cases, it's best to reinstall from the store, where apps haven't been discontinued.

Comment: Rowland:  Malware could also  be inserted into videos which were not encrypted.  However it doesn't matter anyhow, it is what it is.

Comment: @NeilTurner We can remove application files from another phone by setting SD card as `Store new apps` option in `Storage Sense`. It will prompt to delete those files from other phone.